# Call activity located in an external android library (jar)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I am trying to call an **activity** which is **located in an external android library.**

I have **two projects** in my eclipse :
-SuperApp (contains MainActivity which has a "Start Calculator Activity" button)
-AdditionLibrary (contains a CalculatorActivity which has a "This is the calculator activity" TextView)

Here are the source code for the activities : 
https://gist.github.com/poiuytrez/4714770

**If I reference the application** from the SuperApp using the project properties->Android->Library
http://tinypic.com/r/2v31s8z/6
The app **works** fine.

**If I export the jar** of AdditionLibrary (http://tinypic.com/r/30m9wld/6) to add it in the libs folder of SuperApp, and then add the jar in the Java Build Path (http://tinypic.com/r/2efksk0/6), when I launch the app **I have the following issue** :

```
"android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException".
```

http://tinypic.com/r/2hnbb6q/6

I have looked everywhere but I do not find the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Can you please, paste your log here,so that we can have more detail about your error.

Comment: Here you go : http://pastebay.net/1182129

Comment: Thanks..I have gone through your log.It clearly states the resource error. If you are using your costume resources in library project than it's a bad idea to use the jar, well if you still want it, than you may also keep an copy of your resource used in library in your calling application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding jar file into your project, then you need to all the resources used in the library project.

Including menu, drawable, layout etc..

**For Example :**

This is used in your `CalculatorActivity.java` file :

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_calculator, menu);
```

so, you need to add menu file called `activity_calculator.xml` to your `SuperApp` Application.

Comment: Thank you. I had to remove the "res" folder when I exported the jar. I had also to add activity_calculator.xml menu file and layout file. It now works.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cant make jar file of the android library. You have to use as android library project
http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

Comment: You can find several examples of projects which includes an Activity in a jar file. Card.io (https://www.card.io/integrate/) is an example of jar library which includes an activity.